# How is symmetry in an inequality determined?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, rearrangement-inequality

I was reading a book about inequalities, in that I found that $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}>1\tag{1}$$ is a symmetric inequality in $a$,$b$,$c$. But if I change the order from $(a,b,c)$ to $(a,c,b)$, I am not getting the same inequality which is the basic definition of symmetric inequality. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my attempt: After changing the order to $(a,c,b)$, we get $$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{a}>1$$ this is clearly not same as $(1)$.

Here is the excerpt from the book which I am studying: [image]

Comment: Are a, b, c positive numbers

Comment: @Manthanein it is not given in the book that a,b,c are positive numbers

Comment: The cyclic symmetry is (a, b, c)  ; (b, c, a) ; (c, a, b) and (a, c, b)  is not symmetric with the given sequence

Comment: @Manthanein I did not arrive, this is given in a book

Comment: @Manthanein I am talking about symmetric, not cyclic

Answer (score 2):

It's not symmetric inequality because the permutation $(a,b,c)\rightarrow(a,c,b)$ gives another inequality:
$$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}>1.$$

By the way, the inequality $$a+b+c>abc$$ is symmetric.

Comment: So the book is wrong?

Comment: If the book says that it's a symmetric inequality then the book is wrong.

Comment: I agree $a+b+c>abc$ is symmetric, but this is a big claim that the book is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: The book is wrong. The inequality is cyclic but not symmetric.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Ok... Thanks for clarifying!!

Comment: Weijun Zhou is right i.e. the book is wrong.  I think that the author got confused with cyclic And symmetric

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This is the book http://www.springer.com/in/book/9780387989426     see section 2.7

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a small doubt, wasn't symmetric defined in this way for relations on a set $S$. ([like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation)) The  definition has tuples of only two elements. So, how do you extend the definition of "symmtericity" to a triplet?

Comment: @GaurangTandon You can define "symmetry" for a triplet as $P(a,b,c) = P(a',b',c')$ for  every permutation of $(a',b',c')$ in $(a,b,c)$ $$P(a,b,c)=P(a,c,b)=P(b,a,c)=P(b,c,a)=P(c,a,b)=P(c,b,a)$$

Comment: @Vivek This is awesome!!! :)

Comment: @Vivek Ok thanks!